# Are custom events possible in service workers?

Tags: javascript, service-worker, progressive-web-apps

Is it possible to send & receive arbitrary events with a service worker?

I am thinking of something like:

```
// main.js
navigator.serviceWorker.triggerEvent('hello');

// service-worker.js
self.addEventListener('hello', someFunction);
```

I understand that I could simulate this behavior with [postMessage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/postMessage) (like using `postMessage('hello');`), but I am still curious.

Comment: It seems like you've answered your own question in the OP :) Or are you looking for alternate methods to send custom events (instead of `postMessage`)? If so, why?

Comment: Yeah, I am just curious. Like, are these events "hard-coded" or is there an API for creating them. I've also seen it in some example code (that I can no longer find).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Those events are "hard-coded" [from the spec](https://www.w3.org/TR/service-workers/#document-context-events), so the answer is **no, it's not possible.**

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Apart from the truly "arbitrary" requirement, I disagree strongly with the accepted answer based on the following documentation: -
[Service Worker Extensibility](https://w3c.github.io/ServiceWorker/#extensibility)
, [Example from developer Mozilla](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ServiceWorkerGlobalScope/message_event)
Similar to the OPs requirement to instantiate a SW based on a user-defined event, I have been desperately awaiting the arrival of ServiceWorkerRegistration.travelManager (getSubscription(), permissionState(), subscribe())

The subscribe() method will take event filter options such as (minMsecs/meters between position updates, accuracy, etc)

A new ServiceWorker "Travel" event will be created. The UserAgent must be able to re-instantiate a previously terminated ServiceWorker on the strength of this event.

One GeoLocation watcher per UserAgent sounds battery-friendly to me!

[W3C discussion](https://github.com/w3c/ServiceWorker/issues/745)
[Chrome bug details](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=383125)